# How to get a windowed function working in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I know that there are quite many threads on "Windowed functions can only appear in the select or ORDER BY clases" topic, but I have read them through and just don't seem to get any of those trick to work for me. So here I go.

My Query you can see below the line. I have highlighted the part of the Query which is "causing" me issues or problems. The thing is that I would like to get

"**LocalCurrentAmount not between -1.000000 and 1.000000"**

in somehow. I have tried the CTE versioon, but somehow didn't work and my declare tables and then the details view started causing problems.

Would really appreciate your help!
Jaanis

---

```
declare @exceptions1 table (CustomerCode varchar(7), Exception_comment varchar(15));
insert into @exceptions1 (CustomerCode, Exception_comment)
VALUES
(3514437,'Exception'),(3500977,'Exception'),(3295142,'Exception'), ...

declare @exceptions2 table (CustomerCode2 varchar(7), Exception_comment2 varchar(15));
insert into @exceptions2 (CustomerCode2, Exception_comment2)
VALUES
(3390437,'VIP SE')  ,(3390438,'VIP SE') ,(3390481,'VIP SE'),    ...

declare @exceptions3 table (CustomerCode3 varchar(7), Exception_comment3 varchar(15));
insert into @exceptions1 (CustomerCode, Exception_comment)
VALUES 
(1530350, 'DK Exception'), (1533834, 'DK Exception'), (1530002, 'DK Exception'), ...

with Details as 
(
    select ard.AccountsReceivableHeaderID, sum(ard.TransactionAmountOC) as DetailAmountOC , Max(DetailSequenceCode) as DetailSequenceCode, Max( ard.BatchDate) as BatchDate
    from dmbase.fAccountsReceivableDetail ard
    join dmbase.fAccountsReceivable arh on ard.AccountsReceivableHeaderID = arh.AccountsReceivableID
    where ard.BatchDate <= getdate()
    group by AccountsReceivableHeaderID 
)

SELECT 
    comp.CompanyCode
    ,convert(varchar(10),ar.InvoiceDate, 103) as Invoice_date -- dd/MM/yyyy format
    ,case 
        when ar.IsCreditMemo = 'Y' then 'Memo (Credit/Debit)' 
        when ar.InvoiceCode = '0' then 'Payment' 
        else 'Invoice' 
    end as Description
    ,isnull(cm.SummaryInvoiceCode, ar.InvoiceSummaryCode) InvoiceSummaryCode
    ,case
        when len(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '1' then CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode,'-000',ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
        when len(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '2' then CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode,'-00',ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
        when len(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '3' then CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode,'-0',ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
        else CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode,'-',ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
    end as Invoice#
    ,**(ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC
    + 
    case 
        when row_number() over (partition by AccountsReceivableID order by ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 then isnull(vat.vatAdjustment, 0) 
        else 0 
    end
    + 
    coalesce(det.DetailAmountOC, 0)) * coalesce(cer.CurrencyExchangeRate, ar.CurrencyExchangeRate) AS LocalCurrentAmount**
    ,(ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC
    + 
    case 
        when row_number() over (partition by AccountsReceivableID order by ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 then isnull(vat.vatAdjustment, 0) 
        else 0 
    end
    + coalesce(det.DetailAmountOC, 0)) AS CurrentAmount
    ,ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC
    + 
    case 
        when row_number() over (partition by AccountsReceivableID order by ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 then isnull(vat.vatAdjustment, 0) 
        else 0 
    end as OriginalInvoiceAmountOC
    ,ar.InvoiceCurrencyCode
    ,cust.CustomerCode
    ,upper(cust.CustomerName) as CustomerName
from 
    dmbase.fAccountsReceivable ar
    INNER JOIN dmbase.dlocation loc
        ON loc.LocationID = ar.LocationID
    INNER JOIN dmbase.dCustomer cust
        ON cust.CustomerID = ar.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN dmbase.VatAdjustment vat
        on ar.InvoiceCode = vat.contractNumber 
        and ar.InvoiceSequenceCode = vat.invoiceSequence 
        and cust.CustomerCode = vat.CustomerNumber
        and loc.CompanyCode = vat.companyCode
    inner join dmbase.dCompany comp
        on (ar.CompanyID = comp.CompanyID)
    left join dmbase.dAccountsReceivableInvoiceStatus aris 
        on (aris.ARInvoiceStatusAMID=ar.ARInvoiceStatusAMID)
    left hash join Details det
        on (ar.AccountsReceivableID = det.AccountsReceivableHeaderID)
    left join dmbase.dCurrencyExchangeRate cer
        on (comp.CompanyCode = cer.CompanyCode 
        and ar.InvoiceCurrencyCode = cer.CurrencyCode
        and case ar.InvoiceDate when '1900-01-01' then getdate() else ar.InvoiceDate end between cer.ValidFrom and cer.ValidTo)
    left join dmbase.fContractClosedHeader ccd  
        on  ccd.ContractNumber = ar.InvoiceCode 
        and ccd.ContractSeqNumber = ar.InvoiceSequenceCode 
        and ccd.CompanyID = ar.CompanyID  
        and ccd.ContractNumber!='0' 
        and ccd.CreditMemoContractNumber != '0'
    left join dmbase.fAccountsReceivableHeader cm 
        on ccd.CreditMemoContractNumber  = cm.ContractNumber 
        and ccd.CreditMemoSequenceCode = cm.ContractSeqNumber 
        and cm.CompanyID = ccd.CompanyID
where 
    (aris.ARInvoiceStatusCode = 'OP' or (ar.LastPaymentDate >= getdate()) 
    or (ar.TotalAdjustmentsAmountOC <> 0 and ar.CurrentAmountLC = 0 
    and (ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC + isnull(vat.vatAdjustment, 0) ) + coalesce(det.DetailAmountOC, 0) <> 0)
    )
    and ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC <= 0
    and ar.IsCreditMemo = 'Y' -- ainult Memo (Credit/Debit)
    and cust.InternalCustomerType = 'External'
    and cust.CustomerName not in ('RR AJM', 'RAMIRENT', 'Ramirent')
    and cust.CustomerName not like '%[7][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'  
    and ar.InvoiceDate <= EOMONTH(getdate(),-3
    and cust.CustomerCode NOT IN
        (select CustomerCode from @exceptions1
        union
        select CustomerCode2 from @exceptions2
        union
        select CustomerCode3 from @exceptions3)
order by Invoice_date
```

Comment: There a lot of syntax errors in that code... For example you have `**(ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC` and later on `AS LocalCurrentAmount**`. What does the `**` represent? it's not T-SQL syntax. You also have`EOMONTH(getdate(),-3` where you're missing a right parenthesis for `EOMONTH` and `EOMONTH` only accepts 1 input parameter. Also, `{datetime value} - {int value}` is quite bad practice, you should really be using `DATEADD()`.

Comment: Hey Larnu,
I double checked my code and it seems the LocalCurrentAmount** seems to be a coping error, also the missing right parenthesis. 
But thanks for point out the {datetime value} - {int value}, I have corrected it now to dateadd!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a Window function, like you said in your post, you can't use it in the `WHERE` clause. The common solution, therefore, is to use a CTE and reference it in the `WHERE` outside of it. I've used your CTE, however, without any kind of sample data this is a total guess. I've also left a lot of comments for you, and changed some other parts of the SQL, as some of the clauses you have will effect your query's performance.

```
WITH
Details AS
    (SELECT ard.AccountsReceivableHeaderID,
            SUM(ard.TransactionAmountOC) AS DetailAmountOC,
            MAX(DetailSequenceCode) AS DetailSequenceCode,
            MAX(ard.BatchDate) AS BatchDate
     FROM dmbase.fAccountsReceivableDetail ard
          JOIN dmbase.fAccountsReceivable arh ON ard.AccountsReceivableHeaderID = arh.AccountsReceivableID
     WHERE ard.BatchDate <= GETDATE()
     GROUP BY AccountsReceivableHeaderID),
Summary AS(
    SELECT comp.CompanyCode,
           CONVERT(varchar(10), ar.InvoiceDate, 103) AS Invoice_date, -- dd/MM/yyyy format
           CASE
                WHEN ar.IsCreditMemo = 'Y' THEN 'Memo (Credit/Debit)'
                WHEN ar.InvoiceCode = '0' THEN 'Payment'
                ELSE 'Invoice'
           END AS Description,
           ISNULL(cm.SummaryInvoiceCode, ar.InvoiceSummaryCode) AS InvoiceSummaryCode,
           CASE
                WHEN LEN(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '1' THEN CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode, '-000', ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
                WHEN LEN(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '2' THEN CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode, '-00', ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
                WHEN LEN(ar.InvoiceSequenceCode) = '3' THEN CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode, '-0', ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
                ELSE CONCAT(ar.InvoiceCode, '-', ar.InvoiceSequenceCode)
           END AS Invoice#,
           (ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC + CASE
                                              WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountsReceivableID ORDER BY ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 THEN ISNULL(vat.vatAdjustment, 0)
                                              ELSE 0
                                         END + COALESCE(det.DetailAmountOC, 0)) * COALESCE(cer.CurrencyExchangeRate, ar.CurrencyExchangeRate) AS LocalCurrentAmount,
           (ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC + CASE
                                              WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountsReceivableID ORDER BY ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 THEN ISNULL(vat.vatAdjustment, 0)
                                              ELSE 0
                                         END + COALESCE(det.DetailAmountOC, 0)) AS CurrentAmount,
           ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC + CASE
                                             WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountsReceivableID ORDER BY ar.InvoiceCode) = 1 THEN ISNULL(vat.vatAdjustment, 0)
                                             ELSE 0
                                        END AS OriginalInvoiceAmountOC,
           ar.InvoiceCurrencyCode,
           cust.CustomerCode,
           UPPER(cust.CustomerName) AS CustomerName
    FROM dmbase.fAccountsReceivable ar
         INNER JOIN dmbase.dlocation loc ON loc.LocationID = ar.LocationID
         INNER JOIN dmbase.dCustomer cust ON cust.CustomerID = ar.CustomerID
         LEFT JOIN dmbase.VatAdjustment vat ON ar.InvoiceCode = vat.contractNumber
                                           AND ar.InvoiceSequenceCode = vat.invoiceSequence
                                           AND cust.CustomerCode = vat.CustomerNumber
                                           AND loc.CompanyCode = vat.companyCode
         INNER JOIN dmbase.dCompany comp ON (ar.CompanyID = comp.CompanyID)
         LEFT JOIN dmbase.dAccountsReceivableInvoiceStatus aris ON (aris.ARInvoiceStatusAMID = ar.ARInvoiceStatusAMID)
         LEFT HASH JOIN Details det ON (ar.AccountsReceivableID = det.AccountsReceivableHeaderID)
         LEFT JOIN dmbase.dCurrencyExchangeRate cer ON (comp.CompanyCode = cer.CompanyCode
                                                    AND ar.InvoiceCurrencyCode = cer.CurrencyCode
                                                    AND CASE ar.InvoiceDate WHEN '1900-01-01' THEN GETDATE()ELSE ar.InvoiceDate END BETWEEN cer.ValidFrom AND cer.ValidTo)
         LEFT JOIN dmbase.fContractClosedHeader ccd ON ccd.ContractNumber = ar.InvoiceCode
                                                   AND ccd.ContractSeqNumber = ar.InvoiceSequenceCode
                                                   AND ccd.CompanyID = ar.CompanyID
                                                   AND ccd.ContractNumber != '0'
                                                   AND ccd.CreditMemoContractNumber != '0'
         LEFT JOIN dmbase.fAccountsReceivableHeader cm ON ccd.CreditMemoContractNumber = cm.ContractNumber
                                                      AND ccd.CreditMemoSequenceCode = cm.ContractSeqNumber
                                                      AND cm.CompanyID = ccd.CompanyID
    WHERE (aris.ARInvoiceStatusCode = 'OP'
        OR (ar.LastPaymentDate >= GETDATE())
        OR (ar.TotalAdjustmentsAmountOC <> 0
        AND ar.CurrentAmountLC = 0
        AND (ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC + ISNULL(vat.vatAdjustment, 0)) + COALESCE(det.DetailAmountOC, 0) <> 0)) --Why ISNULL for one, COALESCE for the other? Both will make the query non-SARGable
      AND ar.OriginalInvoiceAmountOC <= 0
      AND ar.IsCreditMemo = 'Y' -- ainult Memo (Credit/Debit)
      AND cust.InternalCustomerType = 'External'
      AND cust.CustomerName NOT IN ('RR AJM', 'RAMIRENT', 'Ramirent')
      AND cust.CustomerName NOT LIKE '%[7][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' --A leading wildcard is going to perform slow
      AND ar.InvoiceDate <= EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())) --I have changed this from EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -3 (which made no sense)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM @exceptions1 E
                      WHERE E.CustomerCode = cust.CustomerCode) --Changed to EXISTS binned UNION you should use UNION ALL if you're doing something like this, it'll be quicker)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM @exceptions2 E
                      WHERE E.CustomerCode = cust.CustomerCode) --Changed to EXISTS binned UNION (you should use UNION ALL if you're doing something like this, it'll be quicker)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM @exceptions3 E
                      WHERE E.CustomerCode = cust.CustomerCode)) --Changed to EXISTS binned UNION you should use UNION ALL if you're doing something like this, it'll be quicker)
SELECT *
FROM Summary
WHERE LocalCurrentAmount NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1
ORDER BY Invoice_date;
```

It's worth noting that the above sql is **completely untested**. I do not have access to your server, or data, so I'm purely relying on "my eye" to note any errors.

Comment: Hi Larnu,
Thanks for the response. I have tested the code and works just as I wanted it to work. Thanks for the help.
I will look more into your comment to help my limited proficiency grow!
Really appreciate your help!

Although I changed  "AND ar.InvoiceDate <= EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())) " DAY to MONTH, so that I'd get the range I'd need.

Comment: @JaanisVeinberg you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote or mark the answer as the solution if it solved the problem for you.

Comment: Did upvote it, but as I just signed up for Stack, my comments are not publicly showde due to my low reputation.

Comment: @JaanisVeinberg Then mark it as a solution, if it fixed the problem. Marking a solution gives you reputation as well; which is far more important for you than myself. It also means if others have a similar query, they will see the answer that helped sovle the problem. :)

Comment: Marked it! Thanks again.